# Flutter: Phoenix rebirth then navigate to a specific page

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I'm working on an app that contains more than one workspace to switch between them.

The user can receive notifications from the workspaces (all of them, even if he is not in this workspace)

When he clicks on the notification, it switches the workspaces (switch then reset the di and every thing then make the rebirth action using flutter_phoenix) then he should navigate to the specific page

The app works very well until finished the rebirth action, then didn't navigate to the specific page, just the home page after switching.

An example with this block of code:

```
Phoenix.rebirth(navigatorKey.currentContext!);
navigatorKey.currentState!.pushNamed(
  taskDetailsRoute,
  arguments: TaskDetailsPageArgs(
    taskId: taskId,
  ),
);
```

That happens only after making this rebirth, It works very well if wanted to navigate if it's in the same workspace.

Comment: Do you get any error or it simply does not work ?

Comment: @Lulupointu It doesn't work and there is not any error

Comment: What if you wait 1 frame to navigate? Like so: WidgetBindings.instance!.addPostFrameCallback(() => navigatorKey...)

Comment: @Lulupointu The same issue